# mostrar datos de select en una tabla (laravel, html, jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, json

Hola a todos espero se encuentren bien, tengo el siguiente dilema: necesito que al seleccionar una opcion de un select se muestren en una tabla una serie de datos (que vienen de tablas relacionadas).

En el controlador tengo la siguiente funcion que me debria retornar los datos, pero solamente el json que me retorna trae los datos de la variable $asignacion

```
public function getMaterialTecnico($id){
    //$tecnico = Tecnico::with('tecnicos')->findOrFail($id);
    //$det="";
    $asignacion = AsignacionMaterial::all()->where('tecnico_id','=',$id);
    //$det= AsignacionMaterial::select('id')->where('tecnico_id','=',$id);
    $detalle = DetAsignacionMaterial::all()->where('asignacion_material_id','=',$id);
    return response()->json([
        'dato' => array(
            //'tecnico' => $tecnico,
            'asignacion' => $asignacion,
            'detalle' => $detalle
        )        ], 200);
}
```

y la funcion jquery que tengo es esta:

```
     function materialesTecnico(){
    var id = $('select[name=tecnico_id]').val();
        $('#tecnico_id').val('');
        //console.log(bodega_id)
        $('#tecnico_id').val(id);
    $.ajax({
            url:"{{ url('/tec/mat') }}"+`/${id}`,
            method:"get",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                var valor = ''
  data.asignacion.forEach(product => {
    valor += "<tr>"+
     "<td>" + product.fecha_asignacion + "</td>"+
     "<tr>";
  })$("#detalles").html(valor);}});
```

al hacer la prueba me muestra el error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Saludos a todos

Comment: Por lo que se ve el backend devuelve una estructura que tiene una propiedad `dato` y dentro de esa la propiedad `asignacion`. Y en el success de ajax estás intentando acceder directamente a `asignacion`.

Comment: ahora al parecer me funciono, una consulta adicional, cuando me va a mostrar los datos en la tabla me borra los encabezados de la tabla, de que manera correcta puedo imprimir sobre la tabla?

Comment: ya lo resolvi, estaba pasando mal los tr...