# pasar parametros de funcion jquery a controlador en laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, rutas

Hola todos como estan? tengo que obtener datos de un par de tablas, mediante eloquent hago uso de joins y en los where necesito pasar dos variables para que funcione la consulta...Para enviar los parametros tengo una funcion jquery que en teoria deberia enviarme los parametors pero me da el siguiente error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined**

esta es la funcion que tengo en el controlador:

```
public function getMaterialBodegaServicio($id,$tec){

        $bodegas = Bodega::find($id);
        $tecnicos = Tecnico::find($tec);
        $data = DB::table('ingreso_materials')
        ->Join('det_ingreso_materials','det_ingreso_materials.ingreso_material_id','=','ingreso_materials.id')
        ->Join('materials','materials.id','=','det_ingreso_materials.material_id')
        ->Join('bodegas','bodegas.id','=','det_ingreso_materials.bodega_id')
        ->Join('servicios','servicios.id','=','ingreso_materials.servicio_id')
        ->Join('tecnicos','servicios.id','=','tecnicos.servicio_id')
        ->where('tecnicos.servicio_id',$tec)
        ->where('det_ingreso_materials.servicio_id',$id)
        ->select('bodegas.nombre_bodega','det_ingreso_materials.bodega_id','servicios.servicio','ingreso_materials.servicio_id','materials.detalle','det_ingreso_materials.material_id','tecnicos.id','det_ingreso_materials.cantidad')
        ->get();

        return $data;



        }
```

y esta es la jquery que tengo para que al seleccionar un elemento del select llame a la ruta y me carge en otro select los datos asociados a ese id:

```
 $('#tecnico').on('change', function(){
            var bodega_id = $(this).val();
            var tecnico_id = $(this).val();
                $('#bodega_id').val('');
                $('#tecnico').val('');
                //console.log(empresa_id)
                //$('#material_id').val(bodega_id);
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"{{ url('/bod/mat/serv/') }}"+`/${bodega_id}`+`/${tecnico_id}`,
                        method:"get",
                        //data:{select:select, value:value, dependent:dependent},
                        success:function(result){
                            //console.log(result.data)
                            var opciones = '';
                            var opciones = '<option value="" disabled="disabled">--Seleccione Material a Asignar--</option>';
                            result.data.forEach(element => {
                                opciones += `<option value="${element.id}">${element.detalle}</option>`;
                            });
                            $("#materiales").html(opciones)
                            //$("#servicio_id").append(opciones);
                        }
                    })

                   /*  $("#materiales").on('change',function(){
                        var material_id = $("#materiales").val();
                        $('#material_id').val(detalle);
                    }); */
        });
```

La ruta la tengo asi: Route::get('/bod/mat/serv/{id}/{tec}',[PersonaLogisticaController::class, 'getMaterialBodegaServicio'])->name('test8');

Via browser si ingreso los parametros recibo la info bien teoricamente...

Saludos a todos

Comment: Y será porque `result.data` dá undefined. ¿Que te devuelve si haces un `console.log(result)`? Nota que es lo mismo que planteabas en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426800/mostrar-datos-de-select-en-una-tabla-laravel-html-jquery)

Comment: el console da: undefined

Comment: No puede ser, `result` sí está definido cuando declaras la función `success`, estarás haciendo un log de `result.data`

Comment: cierto me confundi, ahi me muestra data y dentro el array con la info

Comment: tal vez estoy haciendo mal algun procedimiento: lo que debo lograr es que al seleccionar a un tecnico desde el select (ejemplo tomara el id 1) y que en base a este id se cargue un segundo select (bodegas) y finalmente caragr los materiales a un tercer select

Answer (score 0):

resuelto, finalmente quedo asi:

```
$('#tecnico').on('change', function(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            $('#servicio_id').val('');
            //console.log(empresa_id)
            $('#servicio_id').val(id);
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ url('/tec/serv') }}"+`/${id}`,
                method:"get",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var jsonData=data
                    //console.log(jsonData)
                    $('#servicio').val(jsonData.data.servicio.servicio);
                    $('#servicio_id').val(jsonData.data.tecnico.servicio_id);
                    $('#tecnico_id').val(jsonData.data.tecnico.id);
                    $('#tecnico_id').val(jsonData.data.tecnico.id);

                    //carga el select de la bodega prinicial asociado al servicio del tecnico
                    var opciones = '';
                    var opciones = '<option value="">--Seleccione Bodega--</option>';
                        jsonData.data.bodegas.forEach(element => {
                            opciones += `<option value="${element.id}">${element.nombre_bodega}</option>`;
                        });
                    $("#bodega").html(opciones)

                }
            })
        });

$('#bodega').on('change', function(){
    var bodega_id = $(this).val();
    var servicio_id = $('#servicio_id').val();
    //$('#bodega_id').val('');
    //$('#tecnico_id').val('');
    //console.log(empresa_id)
    //$('#bodega_id').val(bodega_id);
    //$('#tecnico_id').val(tecnico_id);
    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ url('/bod/mat/serv/') }}"+`/${bodega_id}`+`/${servicio_id}`,
        method:"get",
        //data:{select:select, value:value, dependent:dependent},
        success:function(result){
            //console.log(result.data)
            var opciones = '';
            var opciones = '<option value="">--Seleccione Materiales a Asignar--</option>';
            result.data.forEach(element => {
                opciones += `<option value="${element.id}">${element.detalle}</option>`;
            });
            $("#materiales").html(opciones)
            //$("#servicio_id").append(opciones);
        }
    })
});
```